# Drupal 7: Hard coding layout in Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In one of my D7 project, I used several tpl files for view templating. Please see below some of the tpl file codes. However, my client has been reviewed the codes and commented:

> Hard coding layout in Views. Instead of creating blocks with different display layouts (same display layouts are the same in other places), there is a code with the layout on the Views result that it depends on the key of the result.

I cannot understand the points he saying. If you wish, I can share some additional coding / admin panel screen shots

Here are some tpl files:

1.

```
<div id="programmes" class="page-section">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="section-heading"><?php echo t('OUR');?> <?php echo count($rows); ?> <?php echo t('key Programmes');?></h1>
      <h3><?php echo t('The XXX operate');?> <?php echo count($rows); ?> <?php echo t('key programmes to ensure the greatest global impact:');?></h3>
      <div class="programblock" >
      <?php
       if($rows) {
       $count = 1;
       foreach($rows as $id => $row)
       {
            $title       = $view->render_field('title', $id);
            $description = $view->render_field('field_programme_description', $id);
            $image       = $view->render_field('field_programme_image', $id);
            $icon        = $view->render_field('field_programme_icon', $id);
            $color       = $view->render_field('field_programme_background_color', $id);
        ?>  
          <a href="#" class="programcard w-inline-block" style="background-color:<?php echo !empty($color) ? $color : '#FFFFFF' ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="progimage">
              <div class="programtext">
                  <div class="w-clearfix">
                      <div class="progtabicon smallpti"><?php echo $icon; ?><br></div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <h2 class="progtitle"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                      <div><?php echo $description; ?></div>
                      <div class="readmorecard"><?php echo t('Read More...'); ?></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
       <?php
          $count++;
       }
       }
       ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

2.

```
<div id="s5" class="relevant-news">
    <div class="container w-clearfix">
        <h3 class="section-heading"><?php echo t('Related content'); ?></h3>

        <?php
        if ($rows) {
            foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
                $image = $view->render_field('field_image', $id);
                $body = $view->render_field('body', $id);
                $title = $view->render_field('title', $id);

                $date = $view->render_field('field_news_publist_date', $id);
                $formatted_date = date('d F Y', strtotime($date));

                $programme = $view->render_field('field_news_programme', $id);
                $type = $view->render_field('field_tags', $id);
                ?>
                <div class="_4-block nomar4">
                    <a href="#" class="nl2 w-inline-block">
                        <div class="tag" data-ix="tagtext"><span class="cblu"></span><span class="uhcgreen"> </span><span class="jyel"></span><br></div><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="image" class="cardimage">
                        <div class="card-text">
                            <div class="cardtitle"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
                            <div class="tagtext alt"><?php echo $formatted_date; ?></div>
                            <div><?php echo $body; ?></div>
                            <div class="tagtext alt"><?php echo $programme; ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pagetype news">
                            <div><span class="fa"></span> <?php echo $type; ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
        <?php
            }
        }
?>


    </div>
    <div class="container"><a href="#" id="more" class="button reverse w-button"><span class="fa"></span> <?php echo t('View all News &amp; Media'); ?></a></div>
</div>
```

3.

```
<?php  global $base_url;?>
<?php
   if(!empty($rows)){
    $articles = array();
    $video    = array();
    $gallery  = array();
    $carousel = array();
    foreach($rows as $article){
        $nid = $article['nid'];
        $node = node_load(trim($nid));
        if($node->type == 'article'){
            $articles[] = $nid;
        }elseif($node->type == 'news_video'){
            $video[] = $nid;
        }elseif($node->type == 'news_gallery'){
           $gallery[] = $nid;
        }
        $slider = 0;
        if($node->type != 'article'){
            $carousel[] = $nid;
        }
    }
    $items = array();
    $count = 0;
    if(!empty($carousel)){
            $slider = 0;
            foreach($carousel as $nid){
                $items[$slider][] = $nid;
                $count++;

                if(($count % 5) == 0) {
                $slider++;
                }
            }
    }
?>


    <!--Show stiky images-->
    <div class="container w-clearfix">
      <?php
        $i = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($articles); $i++){
        $nid                = (int) $articles[$i];
        $node               = node_load(trim($nid));
        $title              = $node->title;
        $image              = file_create_url($node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']);
        $news_type_id       = $node->field_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];
        $news_type          = taxonomy_term_load($news_type_id);
        $programmes         = $node->field_news_programme[LANGUAGE_NONE];
        $type_name          = $news_type->name;
        $type_icon          = path_icon($news_type->field_news_icon[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['icon']);
        $description        = !empty($node->field_short_description[LANGUAGE_NONE]) ? $node->field_short_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : "";
        $date               = $node->field_news_publist_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
        $program_name       = array();
        $program_short_name = array();
        $node_url           = drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $nid);
      ?>
      <div class="_2block nomar special">
        <a href="<?php print $node_url;?>" class="nl2 bgimage w-inline-block" style="background-image:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(21, 36, 49, 0), #152431), url('<?php echo $image;?>');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;">
          <div class="pagetype">
            <div><span class="fa fa-<?php print $type_icon;?>"></span> <?php echo $type_name;?></div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-text"></div>
          <?php if(!empty($programmes)){ ?>
                <div class="tag">
                   <?php foreach($programmes as $key2 => $pro){
                       $programme            = taxonomy_term_load($pro['tid']);
                       $bundle               = $programme->field_icon_programme[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['bundle'];
                       $icon                 = path_icon($programme->field_icon_programme[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]);
                       $program_name[]       = $programme->name;
                       $program_short_name[] = $programme->field_short_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
                       ?>
                        <i class="<?php echo $icon;?>"></i>
                   <?php } ?>
                    <br>
                </div>
          <?php } ?>
          <div class="card-text forcedown">
                <div class="cardtitle bigct"><?php echo $title;?></div>
                <div class="tagtext alt"><?php echo date("d M Y", strtotime($date));?></div>
                <div><?php echo $description;?></div>
                <?php if(!empty($program_short_name)){?>
                <div class="tagtext"><?php echo implode($program_short_name, ', ');?></div>
                <?php }?>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php
            if($i == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
      ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: First , It's not a good practice to use functions into .tpl file. Second , if you need to modify display you cannot because you modify directly views template instead use dynamical display , if view is used under several display (full page , into blocs, etc..) , you have the same rendering for all . Best practice is to use a template for all display from view , please read https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/group/views_templates/7.x-3.x

Comment: And https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/_views_theme_functions/7.x-3.x

Comment: @Fky First, as you said, I understand that I cannot use "taxonomy_term_load" such functions in the .tpl files. Instead, I should use these functions in template.php file. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Fky Second, I'm not really aware of "dynamic display of view". I'm not so much experience in Drupal. I'm Googling this but if you have any examples, you can provide me the same.

Comment: @Fky It would be god if you make this as answer. Like, take one of the view as I mentioned and modify some codes for "dynamic display" of view. This way, I can know the process.

Comment: @Fky I have found this https://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2014/04/sharing-templates-between-multiple-drupal-views/ . Will it help me?

Comment: Yes it can , but read my answer first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing , view provide several "Display" for one view created. It let you create some various display of this view to handle and manage data/display. 
- You can create a display like a "Page" so your view will have own url. 
- You can create another display like a "Block" , so it provide a block you can add to region

[Small tutorial for view creation](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/views-module-tutorial/create-view)

Second thing is to understand templating hook override available , so you can change html and displaying for a view:

If my view is named "test" and my display is named "block" , i can override with file

```
views-view--test--block.tpl.php
```

[How theming function work](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/_views_theme_functions/7.x-3.x)

Third thing , template must not contain functions calls , it can create some performance issues and it's not a good practice. Only `$variables` must be `echo` or `printed`. 
You can take a look into `views module` , under "themes" folder to understand.

Finally , if you need to modify some data before rendering you have several hooks usable into `custom modules` or `template.php` which allow you to modify it

[List of hooks available](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7.x-3.x)

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks but where the "dynamic display" topic has considered? How can I achive dynamic display as I mentioned in my question?

Comment: "Dynamic display" doesn't exist ,I think it just a formulation to say one view can have several display or can be used at several page so several contextual data (current nid , current tid , etc..)

Comment: I have several view blocks under a view say block1, block2, block3. So, I think, client is asking about to merge the view templates within one instead by creating separate view template files like --block-1.tpl.php, --block-2.tpl.php, --block-3.tpl.php etc.

Comment: So you can use views-view--test.tpl and into it make if statement on view display

Comment: Accurate! That's I already thought. However, how can I use if condition based on what? should I pass any parameter like tag from view? No idea still about passing params from view.

Comment: Dump `$view` into tpl , you'll see all data avaiblable , i'm pretty sure you have display information at this point